# CodeBlocks makefile project always rebuilds

Tags: c++, ide, makefile, codeblocks

I have set up a make project, and I can build my project.

But I have a problem: When I build my project, It is always rebuild (if it is the newest, it will rebuild all the same)?

I have set the Make Config:
[image]

The Build Log doesn't show  the command line "nmake -q -f makefile.nmake",
just show the command line "nmake -f makefile.nmake";

thank you for your response.

PS: My English is poor, I don't know did I describe the problem clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how big your project is.

Anyway, some IDEs are touching the files when parsing the code. That makes the makefile think the files are modified, and that they need to be rebuilt.

How to prevent the rebuild? Not sure. You can try to use another IDE, or not use makefile for your project. The rebuild may happen for files that are opened.

Comment: @iceKing Ok, so we are talking about a big project. Have you tried other IDE, and see if the rebuild happens with it as well?

Comment: thank you for your response. I have the wireshark1.4.6 source code, and it is builded by nmake and not provided MSVS Sln(But wireshark 1.6.5 upper provided). And also it is dificult for me to add it to MSVS, So I chooses the CodeBlock.

Comment: I have another quesion. How can i get the return value of the command line "nmake -q -f makefile.nmake", thank you all the time.